# webpack: how can I generate a JSON file based on the output of another file

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

End goal: generate a JSON file that contains an array of classes that appear in a bundled CSS file.

I'd like to be able to specify the "input file", either as the actual entry name (`main`), or what it is output as (before hash is applied, ie: `main.css`). And then the webpack plugin would parse that file and output the JSON file based on options passed (default would be something like `[name]-some-configurable-suffix.json` or similar.

This JSON file should be regenerated whenever the source it depends on (the bundled CSS) changes.

I've tried using:

```
compiler.hooks.thisCompilation.tap(MyPlugin.name, (compilation) => {
  compilation.hooks.processAssets.tap(
    {
      name: MyPlugin.name,
      stage: Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_SUMMARIZE,
    },
    (assets) => {
      //
    },
  )
})
```

but I can't figure out how to locate the correct asset to parse as the files have their final output name (`main.a494049af4ee.css`, etc).